# Como faço para adicionar mais de duas condições em uma Expression dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Preciso passar uma lista de `Expressions` como parâmetro e criar os 'Ands' da forma mais dinâmica possível.

Só que assim, sempre que eu adicionar uma nova `Expression` na lista, vou ter que alterar a classe que monta a `Expression` também.

```
ParameterExpression c = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Boleto), "Boleto");
var temNegociacao = Expression.IsFalse(Expression.Property(c, "Negociacao"));
var status = Expression.IsTrue(Expression.Property(c, "Status"));
var bolsa = Expression.LessThan(Expression.Property(c, "Bolsa"), Expression.Constant(100.0));
var aberto = Expression.IsTrue(Expression.Property(c, "Aberto"));
var periodoLetivo = Expression.IsTrue(Expression.Property(c, "Periodo"));

Expression<Func<Billet, bool>> condition =
Expression.Lambda<Func<Billet, bool>>(
Expression.And(
Expression.And(temNegociacao,
Expression.And(status,
Expression.And(bolsa,
Expression.And(aberto, periodoLetivo)))), c));

return _dbSet.Where(condition).ToList();
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que você deseja. Quer usar um `And` ou `Or`? Não está conseguindo? Qual o problema?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta. Consegui criar a condição com um and, mas preciso criar a condição a partir de uma lista de Expressions, de forma que quando eu construir a a classe que retorna as expressions e adicionar uma nova expression, ela retorne a expression com todos os And montados

Comment: Pode até ser eu, mas parece que na sua pergunta você não quer ter uma meta, mas quando atingir a meta, quer dobrar a meta. (Os portugueses não vão entender nada :) )

Comment: kkkkk. é isso mesmo, que estou tentando aplicar um padrão automatizado para adicionar os fitlros no Where. Então terei uma lista de Expressions, daí preciso concatenar com and as condições, de forma que eu adicione uma nova, o retorno já saiba concatenar as condições.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Árvores de expressão são formas válidas de construir um predicado para uso com o Entity Framework, mas neste caso acho que você está complicando.

[`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna [`IQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx). O objeto que implementa `IQueryable` não necessariamente é uma lista materializada, então você pode usar `Where` várias vezes, se quiser. Por exemplo:

```
return _dbSet.Where(x => !x.Negociacao)
             .Where(x => x.Status)
             .Where(x => x.Bolsa < 100)
             .Where(x => x.Aberto)
             .Where(x => x.Periodo)
             .ToList();
```

Isto devolve a mesma coisa que a sua expressão, fora que tem uma legibilidade mais interessante.

Aliás, experimente fazer um teste como o abaixo:

```
var sql = ((ObjectQuery)_dbSet.Where(x => !x.Negociacao)
             .Where(x => x.Status)
             .Where(x => x.Bolsa < 100)
             .Where(x => x.Aberto)
             .Where(x => x.Periodo)).ToTraceString();
```

`sql` terá uma sentença SQL. Depois repita para o seu método de montagem de expressão. O resultado deve ser (quase) o mesmo.

Se o objetivo é montar valores de acordo com o que foi preenchido, você pode fazer assim:

```
var sentenca = _dbSet.Where(x => !x.Negociacao);

if (algumaLogicaVerdadeira)
{
    sentenca = sentenca.Where(x => x.Status);
}

/* Aqui você monta sua regra de negócio. No final, devolva a lista */

return sentenca.ToList();
```

Comment: Segui seu conselho e fiz uma classe estática returnando IQueryable.